# shinydashboard box collapse

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, renderui

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
 

trtall <- rbind(rep("A",100),rep("B",100), rep("C",100))
trt <- sample(trtall,80)
agecat.temp <- c(rep("18-40",100), rep("> 40", 100))
agecat <- sample(agecat.temp, 80)
sex <- sample(rbind(rep("M",100),rep("F",100)),80)
race <- sample(rbind(rep("Asian",50),rep("Hispanic",50),rep("Other",50)),80)

df <- data.frame(trt, agecat, sex, race)

 
body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(box(width=12,collapsed=F, collapsible = T, title="Filters", solidHeader = T,status="primary",
               box(width=5, height="220px", status="primary",
                   fluidRow(column(6,uiOutput("uivr1")),
                            column(6,uiOutput("uivl1")))))))
 
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = T),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
  body, skin = "green"
)

 server = function(input, output) {
  reacui1 <- reactiveVal()

   observeEvent(input$vr1,{
      reacui1(as.list(df %>% distinct(!!input$vr1) %>% arrange(!!input$vr1)))
  })

  output$uivr1 <- renderUI(varSelectInput(width = "200px", "vr1",NULL,df))
  output$uivl1 <- renderUI(selectInput("vl1",width="200px",multiple=T,NULL,choices=reacui1()))
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hi,

I am dynamically trying to create UI in shiny app. The logic works fine until I collapse the box in shiny dashboard.

I did following steps and got unexpected results.

1. I select 'trt' in "*vr1*" and choose "A" from "*vl1*".
2. I collapsed the box.
3. Then un-collapsed the box.
4. I select 'agecat' in "*vr1*" - now I still see various treatments (A,B,C) but not distinct age categories (18-40, >40) in "*vl1*"

Can you please help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that the `shown` event is not passed down to the elements which are in a box inside the collapsed box.

Compare this to this slightly changed example:

```r
body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    box(width = 12, collapsed = FALSE, collapsible = TRUE,
        title = "Filters", solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
        # box(width=5, height="220px", status="primary",
            fluidRow(column(6, uiOutput("uivr1")),
                     column(6, uiOutput("uivl1"))
        #     )
        )
    )
  )
)
```

and you see that in this case the second input is properly updated.

You can also use your example, go to the JS console and type `$('.box').trigger('shown')` and you will see that the select input is suddenly updated.

That means the problem is, that `shiny` still believes that the inputs are hidden and because hidden inputs are not updated you observe this behavior.

But this tells us how we can fix it:

1. Workaround is to switch off the `suspendWhenHidden` property. Add this to your server:

   ```r
     session$onFlushed(function() {
       outputOptions(output, "uivl1", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
     })
   ```

   This is however, just fixing the symptom and not solving the issue.
2. Another approach would be to make sure the `shown.bs.collapse` event is also triggered at the box inside the box. For this we can listen to the `shown.bs.collapse` event and once received, wait a bit (800ms) such that the box is fully visible and then inform all `shiny-bound-output` children that they should be shown:

   ```r
   js <- "$(() => $('body').on('shown.bs.collapse', '.box', function(evt) { 
         setTimeout(function(){
            $(evt.target).find('.shiny-bound-output').trigger('shown.bs.collapse');
         }, 800);
      }))"

   body <- dashboardBody(
     tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),
     fluidRow(
       box(width = 12, collapsed = FALSE, collapsible = TRUE,
           title = "Filters", solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
           box(width = 5, height = "220px", status = "primary",
               fluidRow(column(6, uiOutput("uivr1")),
                        column(6, uiOutput("uivl1"))
               )
           )
       )
     )
   )
   ```

This is, BTW, already reported as bug: https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/234